# Unable to visit websites after deleting SelfControl app

Tags: macos

I downloaded the self-control app, blacklisted some websites, then changed my mind. I deleted the app and modified `etc/hosts`.

I still can't visit the websites. I've tried refreshing the browser but the problem still persists.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't have done that… it won't end well :\

From the [Self Control FAQ](https://github.com/SelfControlApp/selfcontrol/wiki/FAQ)

> **Q: How do I disable SelfControl once it has started?**
>
> You can't. That's the idea. Just wait.
>
> "But, but but..." you say.
>
> Seriously, chill out. It's not the end of the world.
>
> The timer will run out and the internet will come back again. In the
>   meantime, you may find comfort in curling up in a ball under your desk
>   and rocking back and forth for a while.
>
> **Q: I deleted the application, will that do anything?**
>
> No. (Except maybe cause problems with the block disappearing at the
>   proper time. Don't do it!)
>
> **Q: I did some stuff with the terminal that I read on a cool tech site, but it didn't work, what do I do now?**
>
> We don't know what you did or why you would follow instructions found
>   on the internet before reading this FAQ. Lesson learned right? Good
>   luck!

I would imagine your solution will be to reinstall it & hope the timer runs out correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the date. It tricks the app into thinking it's a different day and the timers runs out.

Also: delete the app and never touch it again, **not even with a bargepole**.